# Apply condition to opposite of regex pattern

Tags: r

How could I apply this regex so that all data in the column that does not match this regex turns to 'Need' - Currently, if I run this, it applies Need to all that match the regex. The regex pattern should reflect 'A-1234567' - Bonus: is there a way to ignore case for the first letter as well. Thank you.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(`Col2` = str_replace_all(df$`Col2`,'[[:alpha:]]{1}[[:punct:]]{1}[0-9]{7}','Need'))
```

Comment: (1) (Almost) Never use `df$` inside a `%>%`-pipe based on `df`. (2) Can you provide sample data like `dput(.)`, `data.frame(.)`, other R code, or similar? It's difficult to help with regexes when no sample data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(Col2 = if_else(grepl('[[:alpha:]]{1}[[:punct:]]{1}[0-9]{7}', Col2),
                        Col2, 'Need'))
```